# Magento 1.9.1.1 : Create Store View : Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view

Magento Version 1.9.1.1

In adminpanel: /system/manage store/ I Created new website and then created a store for it. When i tried to create store view it shows bellow error(in var/reports)

> a:5:{i:0;s:229:"SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: `` SELECT `core_store`.* FROM `core_store` WHERE (`core_store`.`code`='15', 'uaeview', 'uaeview', '0', '', '', '') ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC ``";i:1;s:2631:"
>   #0 lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>   #1 app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>   #2 lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>   #3 lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_st...', Array)
>
>   \#4 lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`core_st...', Array)
>   #5 lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>   #6 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
>   #7 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(323): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store), Array, 'code')
>   #8 app\code\community\Ameex\Adminlog\Model\Observer.php(29): Mage_Core_Model_Store->load(Array)
>   #9 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Ameex_Adminlog_Model_Observer->getLog(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>   #10 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Ameex_Adminlog_Model_Observer), 'getLog', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>   #11 app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
>   #12 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
>   #13 app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
>   #14 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
>   #15 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
>   #16 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   #17 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   #18 app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   #19 index.php(173): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   #20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:72:"/index.php/admin/system_store/save/key/e7a8f79dab3ffee0d6b234ad08158164/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}

Comment: Try disabling the Ameex_Adminlog Module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the `Ameex_Adminlog` Module as it is causing the issue.